# How to prevent entire page reloading?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

In my page I have two containers. In first container I'll display the list of items and the corresponding item's actions will be displayed in second container.

I have an option that, at run time I can add a new item in a first container through a link named " create item".

I am using the following $http call to add an item at run time,

```
$scope.createItem = function() {
    $http({method:"POST",
        url:"/sample/addItem"
    }).success(function(data) {                     
        window.location.href = "/sample/pages/items.html";
    })              
};
```

Whenever I click the "create item" link a new item will be added in first container dynamically but the entire items.html page reloads.

I need to avoid reloading of entire page. Only my first container should reload after I click the link.

Comment: That's not the way to use AJAX calls. You should not redirect a new page, but modify the current one using JQuery to add / remove data from the DOM.

Comment: `window.location.href` will reload the page don't use it

Comment: ya but what else i can use instead of window.location.href to redirect to a page as well prevent entire page loading. but i have both the containers in items.html only....when i add new item only first container should reload in same items.html page

Comment: forget about the jQuery, if you have angularjs do it angular way, post more code and I'll make a working example for you as I have a feeling you got something wrong

Answer (score 0):

jQuery helps to load container the partially. Try

```
http://api.jquery.com/load/
```

.load() helps to load only the specified container with the response.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't window.use **location.href**, you can use **$location** for that purpose:

```
function myCtrl($scope, $http,$location){
$scope.createItem = function() {
    $http({method:"POST",
            url:"/sample/addItem"
        }).success(function(data) {                     
           $location.path = "/items";
        })              
    };
}
```

your path **items** should be registered in your route provider.

Comment: can u pls tel me how to do with route provider??

Comment: how are you configuring your routes in the angular app?, can you post that?